# Creating Pandas DataFrames from a dictionary containing various CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I want to create 3 dataframes (i.e., gs, test and train) from the following dictionary:

```
datasets = {
  "gs": "gender_submission.csv",
  "test": "test.csv",
  "train": "train.csv"
}
```

Is it possible to create a for loop to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is easy to import every dataset first (with the `pandas.read_csv()` function) and then use `pandas.concat()` ([info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)) to put them toghether.

Comment: I don't want to concat them, rather I want to load them into different datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do something like:

```
listDataFrames=[]
for key in datasets:
    listDataFrames.append(pd.read_csv(datasets[key]))
```